# Cassandra bulk insert solution

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have a java program run as service , this program must insert 50k rows/s (1 row have 25 column ) to cassandra cluster.

My cluster contain 3 nodes, 1 node have 4 cpu core (core i5 2.4 ghz) , 4 gb ram.

i used Hector api, multithread, bulk insert but the performance is too low as expect (about 25k rows /s ).

Any one have suggest another solution for that. Is there cassandra support an internal bulk insert (without use Thrift).

Answer (score 1):

Astyanax is a high level Java client for Apache Cassandra. Apache Cassandra is a highly available column oriented database.
Astyanax is currently in use at Netflix. Issues generally are fixed as quickly as possbile and releases done frequently.

https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax

Comment: As for 2019: Astyanax is no longer developed

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck creating sstables and loading them directly. There is a **sstableloader**
tool included in the distribution as well as a JMX interface. You can create the sstables using the *SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter* class.

Details [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to bulk-insert data into Cassandra is **sstableloader** an utility provided by Cassandra in 0.8 onwards. For that you have to create sstables first which is possible with **SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter** more about this is described [here](http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/02/cassandra-bulk-loader.html)

Another faster way is Cassandras BulkoutputFormat for hadoop.With this we can write Hadoop job to load data to cassandra.See more on this [bulkload to cassandra with hadoo](http://shareitexploreit.blogspot.in/2012/03/bulkloadto-cassandra-with-hadoop.html)